# How to create client application to access uddi using java?

Tags: java, client, juddi

I've successfully set up an Apache Juddi v3 on my computer ans know I want to create a client that can publish and discover webservices using java. I have searched in google but i could not find a clear explanation of how to do that as am new in webservice and uddi.

any help please!!!

Answer (score 1):

You want to start with the jUDDI examples. There's a bunch of them.
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-examples/
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-examples/more-uddi-samples/src/main/java/org/apache/juddi/samples/

Note: you didn't specify what version you're using, so some of that code may not compile against what you're using. Most solutions should be obvious. If not, try getting checking out the full source (the readme has directions)